# MySQL query neither true nor false

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code which selects certain rows from the table Operators. The connection is successful but when I run the code, I get neither true nor false.
[neither fail message nor successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOnlm.png)

This is the table
[the Operators table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UOuj.png)

Note: Changing the $class to "PushCrew" is intentional.

Besides, what is the better/best way to do this task if I have to get the values in an array?

```
       <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "indicadls02";
$database = "segmentor";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully <br>";

error_reporting(-1);

class gang {

    private $operators;

    public function fetchOperators() {
        $class = get_class($this);
        echo "$class <br>";
        $class = "PushCrew";
        $que = "select * from Operators where Tag = '$class' ";
        echo "$que <br>";
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_queri($conn, $que)) > 0) {
            echo "query is true <br>";
            $operators = $conn->query($que);
            print_r($operators);
        }
        else {
            echo "select query failed <br>";
        }
    }

    public function getOperators() {
        $this->operators = $this->fetchOperators();
        if(get_parent_class($this)) {
            echo "parent exists <br>";
            echo "$this->operators OPS <br>";
            $parent = get_parent_class($this);
            $temp = new $parent();
            $operatorsInherited = $temp->getOperators();
            echo "$operatorsInherited  inherited<br>";
            $this->operators += ($operatorsInherited);
        }
        else {
            echo "tree finished <br>";
        }
        return $this->operators;
    }
}

class bang extends gang{
    private $operators;
};

$ob2 = new bang();
$ob2->fetchOperators();
//$arr = $ob2->getOperators();
//print_r($arr);
```

Comment: `mysqli_queri` need to be `mysqli_query`

Comment: I changed it but even then I am getting query failed.

Comment: is there a reason you're mixing the `myqli` procedural and object orientated styles?

Comment: no, no reason. What would be the correct or better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes and now it works.
1. The database connection was not working when posted outside the class.
2. As mentioned in the answer by @Gjord83, I rectified the error.

Here is the final version(ignore the additional functions):

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","indicadls02","segmentor");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

class PushCrew {

    private $operators;

    public function fetchOperators() {
        echo "inside fetchOperators <br>";
        $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","indicadls02","segmentor");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $operators = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Operators");
        print_r($operators);
        echo "<br>";
    }

    public function getOperators() {
        $this->fetchOperators();
        if(get_parent_class($this)) {
            echo "parent exists <br>";
            $parent = get_parent_class($this);
            $temp = new $parent();
            $operatorsInherited = $temp->getOperators();
            //$operators = array_merge($operatorsInherited);
        }
        else {
            echo "tree finished <br>";
        }
    }

    public function convertConditionToJsCode() {

    }
    public function getJsCode($partialSegments) {
        if (! count($partialSegments)) {
            return null;
        }


    }
}

class ClickEvent extends PushCrew{
    private $operators;
};


$ob2 = new ClickEvent();
$arr = $ob2->getOperators();
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is wrong

```
mysqli_queri
```

correct this with `mysqli_query()`

Comment: I am afraid that this only will not solve the issue. And since it seems TYPO mistake so better to ask in comment not answer

Comment: and also I answered correctly, because the answer is : MySQL query neither true nor false, it's due to the typo.
Please remove -1 in my answer
Thanks

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo. Now the issue is getting the query failed.

Comment: @Gjord83  typo mistake will give him error , not silently proceed